# How to repeatedly write, then read, to and from a pipe as in typing to "cat | tr a-z A-Z"

Tags: c++, linux, pipe

When typing in the command `cat | tr a-z A-Z` (or just `tr a-z A-Z`) I expect the terminal to send my input, line by line, to `tr`'s stdin and, for each line I enter, to see it displayed in all uppercase letters, and this repeatedly until I close stdin with ^D.

I would like to replicate this behaviour in C and execute `tr` with an `exec()` call in a `fork()`ed child, and start interacting with it through `dup2()`'ed `pipe()` file descriptors. I have succeeded in opening a pipe this way, and to send data one way either way, but I don't know how to repeatedly do both to the same command. As it is now, I have to `close()` the file descriptor of the command's input pipe after writing to it before I can start reading the uppercase letters it returns. But then after the first line has been returned, `write()` will of course not work any longer, because that file descriptor now is `EBADF`.

```
int input_fd[2], output_fd[2];

pipe2(input_fd, O_CLOEXEC);
pipe2(output_fd, O_CLOEXEC);

char*buf = new char[1024];
strncpy(buf, "Hello, world!\n", 15);
int pid = fork();

if(pid < 0) {

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

} else if(pid == 0) {

    close(input_fd[1]);
    close(output_fd[0]);

    int err = dup2(input_fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    err = dup2(output_fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

    execlp("/usr/bin/tr", "/usr/bin/tr", "a-z", "A-Z", 0);
    // (error handling omitted)
}

close(input_fd[0]);
close(output_fd[1]);

int err;
err = write(input_fd[1], buf, 15);

close(input_fd[1]); // <--- how else to terminate the input?

err = read(output_fd[0], buf, strlen(buf));

std::cout << buf << std::endl;

strncpy(buf, "xxxxxxx", 8);

err = write(input_fd[1], buf, strlen(buf)); // <--- EBADF, because closed
```

I've been looking for a way to do this for long enough to have questioned its possibility, yet while `cat | tr` is running I was able to verify that `tr`'s PID doesn't change after every new line of input it receives. I have read all the doc's and a lot of questions, and have not found an answer to this problem.

Can this be done in a general fashion? Or is bash just playing magic tricks?

Comment: Ask yourself, what indicates that the end of a line has been reached?

Comment: You're going to have a problem with output buffering inside of `tr`. Generally speaking, if output goes to a terminal, it's written as soon as a line is complete; if output goes to a file or pipe, you'll have to wait until the buffer is full.

Comment: You expect `tr` to use line-oriented I/O. It won't unless you convince it that its input is a terminal. If you want a strictly line-by-line I/O, this is what you will have to do. You will need to open a pseudo-terminal instead of the pipes.

Comment: I'll read up on pseudoterminals, but if that's how `tr` works, then how can it tell when its input is piped in via `cat`?

Comment: `cat | tr 'a-z' 'A-z'` only grabs tr's input. The output is still a terminal. Try `tr 'a-z' A-Z' | cat` and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by user `n.m.`, opening a pseudoterminal allowed me to engage in a dialog with external console programs on a line-per-line basis.

Thanks!